# How do I lean in into a new job without sounding needy

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-environment, colleagues, new-job

I am fortunate to not only have a job in the current climate, but am paid decently well.  However, I am the newest employee in the "team" and about to complete week 4.  I work for a relatively decent size company which likely does not want the bad pr of layoffs. That may change.

We are in week 2 of our mandated "work from home".  Currently, I've been left a bit out in left field without much communication from my team.  I've been teamed with the second newest member of the team.

I feel the mandated quarantine is getting of many of my coworkers.  I know my manager generally winds up working weekends as well.

**How do I volunteer/avail myself to new projects and/or help my colleagues with their tasks without risking agitating my manager and/or coworkers?**  Most of our communication is via skype/email.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing unprofessional about a new employee wanting to make themselves useful. If you and your colleagues were in an office together, they'd be spending time with you to help you learn and become productive. So it is perfectly reasonable to do some of that stuff remotely.

Ask your manager what you can do to help, and how you can get "up to speed." Nobody has a lot of experience with this, so don't expect super-slick remote onboarding procedures.

Ask your manager for ten minutes every other day or so to help guide your learning. Ask for a project or two to help you get started. It's good to show initiative.

Don't worry about taking peoples' time with this. When they decided to hire you, they planned to spend time and effort to bring you into the team.

Comment: +1, Good points... Show Initiative, 10 minutes a-day with the immediate report/manager, and to have reasonable hopes on the remote-onboarding.